# Migrating from Akka Persistence Classic to Akka Persistence Typed

Tags: scala, akka, lagom

I am looking to migrate from Classic Akka Persistence to Akka Persistence Typed. The Lagom documentation found here:[1](https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.6.x/scala/MigratingToAkkaPersistenceTyped.html) says that " **Note** : the only limitation when migrating from from Lagom Persistence (classic) to Akka Persistence Typed is that a full cluster shutdown is required. Even though all durable data is compatible, Lagom Persistence (classic) and Akka Persistence Typed can’t coexist."

Does anyone know if this applies to all persistent entities a server may be aware of? For example, the service I work on has 3 seperate persistent entities. Do I need to migrate all 3 in one go, or can I do one at a time, with a full cluster shutdown each time?

Comment: You can do one at a time.

Answer (score 2):

It’s per Entity. You can migrate them one at a time, but you cannot have a cluster where some nodes run the old version and some run the new, that’s why you need a full shutdown.

Comment: I was just as confused myself a while ago and asked in the Lagom Gitter channel. 
You can see the thread here:

https://gitter.im/lagom/lagom?at=5eb2b36497338850a2ee1d06